# Detect partial font style attributes of text in Word API

Tags: office-js

Is there a way to determine the partial font style of ranges in Word ?

Following codesample shows the font style of a selection

```
$("#test1").click(() => tryCatch(test1));
async function test1() {
  await Word.run(async(context) => {
    console.log('run test1');
    var thisDocument = context.document;
    var range = thisDocument.getSelection();
    range.load('style');
    range.load('font');
    await context.sync();

    console.log(range.font.toJSON());

  });
}
```

with the console output:

```
bold 
null 

color 
"#222222" 

doubleStrikeThrough 
false 

highlightColor 
null 

...
```

If the selection contains a partial formatting like here:

> He**lloWor**ld

the attribute bold shows `null`.
Is there a way to read the partial selection or iterate through each character to determine the correct formatting?

Answer (score 1):

This would be tough to do. Here's some thoughts until someone can provide a better answer.

Any string has to be a range object before you can read its formatting. 
You can search the document for a string, but there's no API where you can search for strings having particular formatting; and there's no way to search for places where formatting changes.

If you could get a reference to the first letter of the original string as a Range object, then you could try to use [Range.getNextTextRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=office-js#getnexttextrange-endingmarks--trimspacing-) (or Range.getNextTextRangeOrNullObject) to step through each letter. The first parameter of that method takes an array of strings to mark the possible end point of the "next" range that you are looking for. See what happens if you put every character in the alphabet and every punctuation mark as a string in that array. If this will step you through the each letter, then you can read the formatting properties of each of those ranges.

Comment: Looking for the first letter initially before searching for it as a starting point and then iterating through the entire range sounds interesting. I tried various search patterns but the most granular I could get working was to use a space as delimiter.
I'll give it a try